# Google Native Client Render Loop

Tags: c++, opengl, pthreads, google-nativeclient

I am attempting to implement a render loop with Google Native Client, I am aware you can not make Pepper API calls on any thread but the main thread, so I am trying to implement the following.
Module() -> Makes New Thread With DoGL_() -> DoGL() Calls Functions With Pepper API Calls In Them On The Main Thread -> DoGL_() calls DoGL() still on separate thread.

I am attempting to do this with Pepper 19 only, and I really do not know enough about threading to fix this. Right now the module just crashes.

Here Is My Code (Not pretty, I am just trying to get the chore code out of the way):

DoGL.h

```
#include "Include.h"



class Context : public pp::Graphics3DClient
{
    pp::Size size;
    bool init_;
    const struct PPB_OpenGLES2 *gles2Interface;
    public: 
        Context( pp::Instance *instance );
        ~Context();
        virtual void Graphics3DContextLost() {
        }
        bool MakeCurrentContext( pp::Instance *instance );
        void FlushContext();
        pp::Graphics3D context;
        void ( *callback ) ( void*, int32_t );
        pp::Instance *ppinstance;
        PPB_Graphics3D* ppb_g3d_interface;
        GLuint programObject;
        GLuint LoadShader( const char *shaderSrc, GLenum type );
        GLuint Init();
        void Draw();
        void DoGL();
        void GLDebug( std::string msg = "" );
        static void FillIn( void* v, int32_t i ) {
        }
        pp::Core *ppb_core_interface;
};

static Context *cjcontext;
void* DoGL_( void* p ) {
    cjcontext->DoGL();
}
void Init_( void *p, int32_t i ) {
    cjcontext->Init();
}
void Draw_( void *p, int32_t i ) {
    cjcontext->Draw();
}
void MakeContext_( void *p, int32_t i ) {
    cjcontext->ppinstance->PostMessage( "Called on the main thread!!!!\n" );
    cjcontext->MakeCurrentContext( cjcontext->ppinstance );
}
void FlushContext_( void *p, int32_t i ) {
    cjcontext->FlushContext();
}
```

DoGL.cpp

```
#include "DoGL.h"
Context::Context( pp::Instance *instance ) : pp::Graphics3DClient( instance )
{
    pp::Module *module = pp::Module::Get();
    gles2Interface = static_cast< const struct PPB_OpenGLES2 * > ( module->GetBrowserInterface( PPB_OPENGLES2_INTERFACE ) );
    init_ = false;
}
Context::~Context() {
    glSetCurrentContextPPAPI( 0 );
}
bool Context::MakeCurrentContext( pp::Instance *instance )
{
    //Is somthing broken?//
    if( instance == NULL ) {
        glSetCurrentContextPPAPI( 0 );
        return ( false );
    }
    if( context.is_null() == true )
    {
        //OpenGL attributes.//
        int32_t attribs[] = 
        { 
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_STENCIL_SIZE, 8,
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_SAMPLES, 0,
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 0,
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_WIDTH, 500,
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_HEIGHT, 500,
            PP_GRAPHICS3DATTRIB_NONE /*Terminate list.*/
         };
        context = pp::Graphics3D( instance, pp::Graphics3D(), attribs );
        if ( context.is_null() == true ) {
            glSetCurrentContextPPAPI( 0 );
            return ( false );
        }
        instance->BindGraphics( context );
    }
    //Get the context.//
    glSetCurrentContextPPAPI( context.pp_resource() );
    glViewport( 0, 0, 500, 500 );
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    return true;
}
void Context::FlushContext()
{
    //Make sure that the flush is not pending.//
    for( unsigned int wait = 0; wait < 1001; ++wait );
    context.SwapBuffers( pp::CompletionCallback( FillIn, ( ( void* ) this ) ) );
}

GLuint Context::LoadShader( const char *shaderSrc, GLenum type )
{
    GLuint shader;
    GLint compiled;
    //Create the shader object.//
    shader = glCreateShader( type );
    if( shader == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    //Load the shader source.//
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &shaderSrc, NULL );
    //Compile the shader.//
    glCompileShader( shader );
    //Check the compile status.//
    glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );
    return shader;
}

GLuint Context::Init()
{
    const char* vShaderStr =  
        "#version 100                \n"
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;   \n"
        "void main()                 \n"
        "{                           \n"
        "   gl_Position = vPosition; \n"
        "}                           \n";
    const char* fShaderStr =  
        "#version 100                               \n"
        "precision mediump float;                   \n"
        "void main()                                \n"
        "{                                          \n"
        "  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); \n"
        "}                                          \n";
    GLuint vertexShader;
    GLuint fragmentShader;
    GLint linked;
    //Load the vertex/fragment shaders.//
    vertexShader = LoadShader( vShaderStr, GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    fragmentShader = LoadShader( fShaderStr, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    //Create the program object.//
    programObject = glCreateProgram();
    if( programObject == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    glAttachShader( programObject, vertexShader );
    glAttachShader( programObject, fragmentShader );
    //Bind vPosition to attribute 0.//
    glBindAttribLocation( programObject, 0, "vPosition" );
    //Link the program.//
    glLinkProgram( programObject );
    //Check the link status.//
    glGetProgramiv( programObject, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked );
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    return programObject;
}


void Context::Draw()
{
    ppinstance->PostMessage( "Drawing!" );
    GLfloat scaler = 1.f;
    GLfloat vVertices[] = 
    { 
        0.0f,  ( scaler * 0.5f ), 0.0f, 
        ( scaler * -0.5f ), ( scaler * -0.5f ), 0.0f,
        ( scaler * 0.5f ), ( scaler * -0.5f ),  0.0f
     };
    ++scaler;
    ppinstance->PostMessage( "Scaler" );
    ppinstance->PostMessage( scaler );
    //Set the viewport.
    glViewport( 0, 0, 500, 500 );
    //Clear the color buffer.//
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    //Use the program object.//
    glUseProgram( programObject );
    //Load the vertex data.//
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
}

void Context::DoGL()
{
    if( init_ == false )
    {
        pp::CompletionCallback cc;
        //ppinstance->PostMessage( "Init is false." );
        cjcontext->MakeCurrentContext( ppinstance );
        for( int i = 0; i < 10001; ++i );
        cc = pp::CompletionCallback( &Init_, 0, 0 );
        ppb_core_interface->CallOnMainThread( 0, cc, 0 );
        init_ = true;
        cjcontext->FlushContext();
    }
    pp::CompletionCallback cc;
    for( int i = 0; i < 101; ++i );
    cc = pp::CompletionCallback( &MakeContext_, 0, 0 );
    ppb_core_interface->CallOnMainThread( 0, cc, 0 );
    for( int i = 0; i < 101; ++i );
    cc = pp::CompletionCallback( &Draw_, 0, 0 );
    ppb_core_interface->CallOnMainThread( 0, cc, 0 );
    for( int i = 0; i < 101; ++i );
    cc = pp::CompletionCallback( &FlushContext_, 0, 0 );
    ppb_core_interface->CallOnMainThread( 0, cc, 0 );
    void *p;
    DoGL_( p );
}

pthread_t reanderHandle;
int threadStatus;

//Standard NaCl chore code.//
class CubeJumpInstance : public pp::Instance
{
    public: 
        explicit CubeJumpInstance( PP_Instance instance ) : pp::Instance( instance ) {
            PostMessage( "Instance create.\n" );
        }
        virtual ~CubeJumpInstance() {
            PostMessage( "Instance destroyed.\n" );
        }
};

class CubeJumpModule : public pp::Module
{
    public: 
        CubeJumpModule() : pp::Module() {
        }
        virtual ~CubeJumpModule() {
            glTerminatePPAPI();
        }
        virtual pp::Instance* CreateInstance( PP_Instance instance )
        {
            glInitializePPAPI( get_browser_interface() );
            pp::Instance *instance_ = new CubeJumpInstance( instance );
            cjcontext = new Context( instance_ );
            cjcontext->ppinstance = instance_;
            cjcontext->ppb_core_interface = this->core();
            threadStatus = pthread_create( &reanderHandle, 0, DoGL_, 0 );
            cjcontext->ppinstance->PostMessage( "Instace done.\n" );
            //pthread_join( reanderHandle, 0 );
            return cjcontext->ppinstance;
        }
};

namespace pp
{
    pp::Module* CreateModule() {
        return new CubeJumpModule();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues here, I'll focus on the main concept:
You don't want a render thread, you can just use swap buffers to drive your render loop.

The basic concept is:

```
// do this to kick things off
CallOnMainThread(Render)

Render()
    if (!init)
        Init();

    MakeContext();
    Draw();
    SwapBuffers(Render);
```

That's it. `SwapBuffers` will schedule the next call to render at the "right" time.

As to why your program is crashing, it could be any number of things, I'd guess your main issue is recursively calling `DoGL` until your stack blows up.